# Scala unit-tests in IntelliJ fail with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError scoverage/Invoker$

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, scoverage

Tests run without any problem in `sbt`, but when you need them in *IntelliJ*, they fail.

```
A needed class was not found. This could be due to an error in your runpath.
Missing class: scoverage/Invoker$
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scoverage/Invoker$
```

I have seen many suggesting during the years how to fix it, but nothing really helped. :)

Comment: you need to add scalacScoverageRuntime jar in your class path

Answer (score 7):

Just perform a rebuild (`Build -> Rebuild Project`).

Intellij is probably storing some temporary/cached files and rebuilding clears them.

Answer (score 1):

Finally discovered a solution, which worked for me:

Temporarely disable `scoverage` plugin for `sbt` project(s) in questions

```
lazy val pipeline: Project = project
...
  .disablePlugins(ScoverageSbtPlugin) // <-- temp
```

**Bonus**: tests are running faster as well.